# Transition in menu CSS3

Tags: css, web, css-transitions

I want to do a menu for my website like this with the transition in each section. I want the red bar move along I click on other sections.

http://piccsy.com/investors/

What is the best way to do that?

I have also tried to do it myself but it doesn't work.

http://alpha.venasanxenxo.com/piccsy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you want to achieve the same effect using **just** CSS3? That menu uses JavaScript. There is no CSS way (yet... it [should come with CSS4](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/)) to change the CSS of an element by clicking an element that isn't its sibling or it's parent.

It is possible, however, to achieve the same effect *for the bar* (for smooth scrolling you need to use JavaScript). But not with that HTML structure.

I've tried a couple of things:

**1.** This http://dabblet.com/gist/3155730 does it with links, but *whenever you click elsewhere on the page (not on the links) the effect disappears*.

The idea in this case is to have a gradient on that element below and to change its size when clicking the links. Do note that the HTML is different, so that the element below can be a sibling of the links.

```
<div class="ui-menu">
    <a class="goto-frame" href="#" tabindex="1">Welcome
        </a><a class="goto-frame" href="#" tabindex="1">Problem
        </a><a class="goto-frame" href="#solution" tabindex="1">Solution
        </a><a class="goto-frame" href="#team" tabindex="1">Team
        </a><a class="goto-frame" href="#traction" tabindex="1">Traction
    </a><a class="goto-frame" href="#product" tabindex="1">Product
        </a><a class="goto-frame" href="#contact" tabindex="1">Contact</a>
    <div class="ui-menu-bottom-line"></div>
</div>
```

The formatting of the HTML does serve a purpose: I've made the links `inline-block` so I cannot have any kind of white space between the closing tag `</a>` and the next opening tag `<a class="goto-frame">`.

The CSS:

```
.ui-menu {
    width: 37em;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.ui-menu a {
    width: 4em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: .1em .5em;
    display: inline-block;
    font: 17px "Arial Narrow", sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.ui-menu a:focus {
    outline: none;
}
.ui-menu-bottom-line {
    width: 35em;
    height: 1px;
    margin: 1em auto;
    background: #d7d7d7
        linear-gradient(left, #d82126 50%, transparent 50%) no-repeat;
    background-size: 5em;
    transition: 1s; 
}
.ui-menu a:nth-child(2):focus ~ .ui-menu-bottom-line,
.ui-menu a:nth-child(2):active ~ .ui-menu-bottom-line {
    background-size: 15em;
}
.ui-menu a:nth-child(3):focus ~ .ui-menu-bottom-line,
.ui-menu a:nth-child(3):active ~ .ui-menu-bottom-line {
    background-size: 25em;
}
/* and so on, I keep adding 10em with every new menu item */
```

Works in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera, IE10 as gradients don't work in IE9 and older (and neither do transitions).

Could be made to work in IE9 and 8 and older by using a pseudo-element on `.ui-menu-bottom-line`, setting its `background` dark red and then changing its `width` on click (instead of changing the background gradient size).

---

**2.** This http://dabblet.com/gist/3155740 works as required even after releasing the mouse button, but it *does not use links*.

HTML

```
<div class="ui-menu">
    <input type="radio" name="mi" id="welcome">
    <label class="goto-frame" for="welcome">Welcome</label>
    <input type="radio" name="mi" id="problem">
    <label class="goto-frame" for="problem">Problem</label>
    <input type="radio" name="mi" id="solution">
    <label class="goto-frame" for="solution">Solution</label>
    <input type="radio" name="mi" id="team">
    <label class="goto-frame" for="team">Team</label>
    <input type="radio" name="mi" id="traction">
    <label class="goto-frame" for="traction">Traction</label>
    <input type="radio" name="mi" id="product">
    <label class="goto-frame" for="product">Product</label>
    <input type="radio" name="mi" id="contact">
    <label class="goto-frame" for="contact">Contact</label>
    <div class="ui-menu-bottom-line"></div>
</div>
```

CSS - same idea, only this time I'm not clicking links - I'm checking radio buttons instead

```
.ui-menu {
    width: 37em;
    padding: 0;
    font: 17px "Arial Narrow", sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}
.ui-menu input[type=radio] { display: none; }
.ui-menu label {
    width: 4em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: .1em .5em;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
.ui-menu-bottom-line {
    width: 35em;
    height: 1px;
    margin: 1em auto;
    background: #d7d7d7
        linear-gradient(left, #d82126 50%, transparent 50%) no-repeat;
    background-size: 5em;
    transition: 1s;
}
.ui-menu #welcome:checked ~ .ui-menu-bottom-line {
    background-size: 5em;
}
.ui-menu #problem:checked ~ .ui-menu-bottom-line {
    background-size: 15em;
}
/* and so on, add 10em to the bg size for each new menu item */
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation on both cases! It really helps me :) I owe you one ;)

Comment: +1 for a very thorough answer. It must have taken ages to write!